# c++ armadillo cast/convert to integer type vector or matrix

Tags: c++, casting, armadillo

How can I **convert a `double`/`float`-typed vector or matrix** to an **`word`/`uword`-typed vector or matrix**?

---

I need to create an indexing array `indices`.

```
vec t = linspace(0, 100);
double freq = 0.25;
indices = floor(t / freq);
```

I'm having trouble on the last line.

Comment: use conv_to: http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#conv_to

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are just dealing with positive values, then the conv_to function of the armadillo package will do exactly the same as the method you are trying to use.

```
vec t = linspace(0, 100);
double freq = 0.25;
ivec indices = conv_to<ivec>::from(t / freq);
```

If you want the results to be the same as the use of the floor function for negative values of t, you could replace the last line with

```
ivec indices = conv_to<ivec>::from(floor(t / freq));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use an iterator to walk through your t vector, and then push back the results of `floor( *it_to_t / freq )` onto your indices vector.

Comment: Not really a source, just experience using vectors on a regular basis.

Comment: So is this better than using `conv_to`?